# Is a function differentiable if it has a removable discontinuity

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

There are many questions on Math Stack Exchange asking if a function is differentiable if it has a **removable discontinuity** at $x=a$.  But, I'm having trouble following the answers. I get the impression, from reading here on Stack Exchange and elsewhere that such a function *is not differentiable* but I don't understand why.

Consider the following equation: $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x}$.  The function is undefined at $x=0$ but it is clearly differentiable.  First by simplifying:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^3}{x}=\frac{d}{dx}x^2=2x$

Or, using the quotient rule:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^3}{x}=\frac{3x^2\cdot x-x^3\cdot 1}{x^2}=\frac{3x^3-x^3}{x^2}=\frac{2x^3}{x^2}=2x$

And, finally, my calculator agrees.

Therefore, it is established that the function is differentiable and has a derivative at every x-value in its domain, including the troublesome $x=0$.

I conclude that a function is differentiable at $x=a$ *if the discontinuity is removable*.

The only thing I can think of that would make this untrue is the idea that *I have changed the original function* $f(x)$ by removing the discontinuity with some algebra and I am really differentiating a different function (call it $g(x)$) that is not quite the same at the one point of interest.  That argument would be more persuasive if I had simply simplified first and then differentiated.  There I was clearly differentiating a different equation.  But, I did not simplify when applying the quotient rule and I obtained the same answer.  So, the argument seems weak, at best.

Comment: This is not really the heart of your error, but you _did_ simplify (in a way that is invalid for $x=0$) when using the quotient rule, in the last step.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto \frac{x^3}x$ isn't discontinuous. It has a singularity, a point where it's undefined. That's different.

Comment: "... but it is clearly differentiable": no, it can't be differentiable where it is undefined.

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^3}{x}=\frac{d}{dx}x^2$ does not make sense when $x=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most correctly, the derivative of $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x}$ is written as $f'(x)=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

Thus $f'(0)=lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}$

Since $f(0)$ is undefined, the limit does not exist and thus the derivative $f'(0)$ also does not exist.

Comment: Thank you Jack for providing an answer that speaks exactly to what I was failing to fully understand. Since f(0) is undefined, I cannot take the limit at x=0.

Answer (score 7):

The map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\frac{x^2}x\end{array}$$is undefined at $0$, and therefore it is meaningless to ask whether or not it is differentiable there. It happens that we can extended it to one and only one continuous function $F\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, which is defined by $F(x)=x$. And it happens that this function *is* differentiable at $0$.

However, if you take$$\begin{array}{rccc}g\colon&\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x>0\\-x&\text{ if }x<0,\end{cases}\end{array}$$then you can extend $g$ to one and only one continuous map $G\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$, which is $G(x)=\lvert x\rvert$, but the function $G$ is *not* differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x^3}x$$ doesn't have a removable discontinuity. It is continuous and differentiable in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, where it equals $x^2$. It is undefined at $x=0$.

---

A discontinuous function is not differentiable at the discontinuity (removable or not).

It the discontinuity is removable, the function obtained after removal is continuous but can still fail to be differentiable.

Comment: First, I assume that $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ means "all real numbers except $0$".  Also, I'm guessing that you are telling me that "undefined at a point" $\ne$ "discontinuous at that point". That's strange. I'll have to review my textbook again to figure that one out.  If $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, then how can I say with confidence that the slope (derivative) at $x=0$ is $0$ (which I believe it is)? Clearly I am missing something important here.

Comment: @RandallBlake: your function is undefined at $x=0$, it can't have a derivative. Review your definition of the dérivative, your confidence is undue.

Comment: So, if I am asked if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$, the correct answer is "no" even though I can calculate a sensible derivative at $x=0$?.  I suppose that it really does boil down to the difference between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that I mentioned in the original post. $f(x)$ has no "point of tangency" at $x=0$, but $g(x)$ does. Somehow that's a little unsatisfying.

Comment: @RandallBlake: for the last time, $f(0)$ is undefined and there is nothing you can say about $f$ at $0$. It is **impossible** to compute the derivative.